# Failed to construct ‘HTMLElement’: Please use the ‘new’ operator

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

I am trying to use AWS Amplify Authentication lib in a re-frame app.
The lib provides a higher order component `withAuthenticator` which is supposed to wrap the main view of your app. I am trying to use `reactify-component` and `adapt-react-class` but unfortunately I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct ‘HTMLElement’: Please use the ‘new’ operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

```
(defn main-panel []
  [:div
   [:h1 "Hello" ]])

(def root-view
  (reagent/adapt-react-class
    (withAuthenticator
      (reagent/reactify-component main-panel))))

(defn ^:dev/after-load mount-root []
  (re-frame/clear-subscription-cache!)
  (aws-config/configure)
  (re-frame/dispatch-sync [::events/initialize-db])
  (reagent/render [root-view]
                  (.getElementById js/document "app")))
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Some discussion of this issue in https://github.com/thheller/shadow-cljs/issues/816 but no full solution as of yet

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with reagent + amplify.

Solved it with 2 changes, but I'm unsure if both are needed

#1 Change output of the google closure compiler to es6 (or higher). Amplify seems to use es6 features that Cannot be polyfilled.

This is for shadow-cljs (shadow-cljs.edn), but this should be possible for other build systems as well.
`{:builds {:app {:compiler-options {:output-feature-set :es6}}}}`

Disclaimer: I switched to shadow-cljs from lein-cljsbuild since I could not get lein-cljsbuild to respect the configuration for es6 output.

#2 Use functional components.

In reagent 1.0.0-alpha1 and up you can change the compiler to produce functional components by default.

```
(ns core
    (:require
      [reagent.core :as r]))


(def functional-compiler (r/create-compiler {:function-components true}))
(r/set-default-compiler! functional-compiler)
```

There are other ways to make functional components. Check the [documentation](https://cljdoc.org/d/reagent/reagent/1.0.0-alpha2/doc/tutorials/react-features#function-components) if you don't like, or can't use, this approach.

Comment: Doing these two things did not fix the situation for me. Still getting the same error as the OP